# QT QGL Black Widget on different pc

Tags: qt, opengl, widget

I wrote a small program for change blindness (this time windows only). It displays 4 images (2 real, 2 grey) via open gl in a qgl widget. It uses painters to do it.

It works quite on my pc. I tried to put it onto an other without qt and placed this gl files into the directory (found the with dependency walker):

libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
mingwm10.dll
QtCore4.dll
QtGui4.dll
QtOpenGL4.dll

It worked well on my pc, outside the QTCreator and without any path set. On each other pc the QGL widgets are just black. The program works normaly (click on button etc) but all images are just black. I looked for the paths but they are all fine. No idea whats happening. The pcs I used have older hardware but nothing to special (older Ati cards with older driver, but i could play Half Life 2 on mid settings, so I assume the drivers are installed).

I got no error message or anything. Any Idea what can be done to fix it? If nothing works I will try to create an ubuntu usb stick with this program in it.

Paths (the paths are correct):

C:\tina_and_mona\pics\1\1.jpg
C:\tina_and_mona\pics\1\2.jpg
C:\tina_and_mona\pics\1\3.jpg
C:\tina_and_mona\pics\1\4.jpg

```
void FlickerImage::updateGL()
{
    //qDebug() << "In UpdateGl Event";
    painter.begin(this);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    painter.drawImage ( QRectF(0,0,800,600), images[image_counter], QRectF(0,0, images[image_counter].width(), images[image_counter].height()));
    //painter.fillRect(QRect(0,0,800,600), QColor(0,0,0,255));
    painter.end();
}

void FlickerImage::loadImages()
{
    busy = true;
    images.clear();

    /*images.append(QImage(QDir::toNativeSeparators(QString("pics") + QDir::separator () + QString::number(counter) + QDir::separator()+"1.jpg")));
    images.append(QImage(QDir::toNativeSeparators(QString("pics") + QDir::separator () + QString::number(counter) + QDir::separator()+"2.jpg")));
    images.append(QImage(QDir::toNativeSeparators(QString("pics") + QDir::separator () + QString::number(counter) + QDir::separator()+"3.jpg")));
    images.append(QImage(QDir::toNativeSeparators(QString("pics") + QDir::separator () + QString::number(counter) + QDir::separator()+"4.jpg")));*/

    images.append(QImage(QDir::toNativeSeparators(QDir::currentPath() + QDir::separator () + QString("pics") + QDir::separator () + QString::number(counter) + QDir::separator()+"1.jpg")));
    images.append(QImage(QDir::toNativeSeparators(QDir::currentPath() + QDir::separator () + QString("pics") + QDir::separator () + QString::number(counter) + QDir::separator()+"2.jpg")));
    images.append(QImage(QDir::toNativeSeparators(QDir::currentPath() + QDir::separator () + QString("pics") + QDir::separator () + QString::number(counter) + QDir::separator()+"3.jpg")));
    images.append(QImage(QDir::toNativeSeparators(QDir::currentPath() + QDir::separator () + QString("pics") + QDir::separator () + QString::number(counter) + QDir::separator()+"4.jpg")));

    qDebug() << "Before output file";
    QFile output("image.log");

    if(!output.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text | QIODevice::Append))
    {
        qDebug() << "Could not open output";
    }

    else
    {
        qDebug() << "image.log could be opened";
        output.write(QString("hi").toAscii());
        output.write(QDir::toNativeSeparators(QDir::currentPath() + QDir::separator () + QString("pics") + QDir::separator () + QString::number(counter) + QDir::separator()+"1.jpg\n").toAscii());
        output.write((QDir::toNativeSeparators(QDir::currentPath() + QDir::separator () + QString("pics") + QDir::separator () + QString::number(counter) + QDir::separator()+"2.jpg\n")).toAscii());
        output.write((QDir::toNativeSeparators(QDir::currentPath() + QDir::separator () + QString("pics") + QDir::separator () + QString::number(counter) + QDir::separator()+"3.jpg\n")).toAscii());
        output.write((QDir::toNativeSeparators(QDir::currentPath() + QDir::separator () + QString("pics") + QDir::separator () + QString::number(counter) + QDir::separator()+"4.jpg\n")).toAscii());
        output.close();
    }

    busy = false;

}
```

Comment: I have experienced black OpenGL output too. It was fixed by updating the graphics card driver. So I recommend that you try that first.

Comment: Its seems to be related to the plugin system. qApp->addLibraryPath("C:/customPath/plugins"); http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/deployment-windows.html#application-dependencies Copying the needed wont work. I will copy all and test it ;)

Comment: Did like this guy recommended: http://deskew.com/blog/tags/qt-plugins-deploy/ But all needed plugin folders in the same dir as your app. Did not work too

Comment: Asked in the qt forums for help too, im realy mad right now... write once, use on every system... my ass http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?236358-QT-4.73-Deploy-plugins-does-not-work

Comment: Are you absolutely sure, that your program can open those jpgs in the other computer? Try to show them in some QLabel to check that jpgs are found and they work.

Answer (score 1):

This probably doesn't fix the problem, but the way the images are added to the list really hurts my eyes ;) Instead of this:

```
images.append(QImage(QDir::toNativeSeparators(QDir::currentPath() + QDir::separator () + QString("pics") + QDir::separator () + QString::number(counter) + QDir::separator()+"1.jpg")));
images.append(QImage(QDir::toNativeSeparators(QDir::currentPath() + QDir::separator () + QString("pics") + QDir::separator () + QString::number(counter) + QDir::separator()+"2.jpg")));
images.append(QImage(QDir::toNativeSeparators(QDir::currentPath() + QDir::separator () + QString("pics") + QDir::separator () + QString::number(counter) + QDir::separator()+"3.jpg")));
images.append(QImage(QDir::toNativeSeparators(QDir::currentPath() + QDir::separator () + QString("pics") + QDir::separator () + QString::number(counter) + QDir::separator()+"4.jpg")));
```

Try something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{
    QString imagePath = QString("%1/pics/%2/%3.jpg")
        .arg(qApp->applicationDirPath()).arg(counter).arg(i);
    if (QFileInfo::exists(imagePath))
    {
        QImage image(imagePath);
        if (image.isNull())
            qDebug() << "ERROR, image load failed: " << imagePath;
        else
            images.append(image);
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "ERROR, cannot find file: " << imagePath;
    }
}
```

Note that you really do not need to convert the file paths to use native separators. You need to do that *only* if you are showing the path to the user. All operating systems that I know (including Windows) work fine with normal slash /.

You are also using `QDir::currentPath()`. My guess is that what you really want is the application's directory, which doesn't need to be the same as the current directory. Use `qApp->applicationDirPath()` instead.

And it usually doesn't hurt to do some error checking.

Comment: Thank you Roku. I did a whole day with error checking. The paths are correct I tested it with output into a debug file. I will test this: http://www.softwareprotection.info/2011/12/application-virtualization-bundle-qt-runtime-to-single-executable-for-windows/ or just simply install the qt runtime with my application.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys,

the missing plugins where the problem. But into the same directory or in the ./plugins/ directory did not work. I just bundled the file, with the FULL QT SDK (yes the 1.65 GB Monster for a 512 KB application), where the versions matched (4.82), since it should be the same (or the local sdk should be same or lower then the build sdk but the same major number in this case 4).

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem with jpeg images, you need to use `QCoreApplication::setLibraryPaths(QStringList &)` and place all your plugins that located `QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.4\mingw\plugins`  into other computer (he will look for them in specified location), you can see what you had set by `QCoreApplication::libraryPaths()`